# Is there such a thing as one true love?

Tags: epistemology

You can often hear couples saying their partner is their one true love in life.

Supposing one half of the couple (either the husband or wife) was not born and did not exist in the world, would the other half go on to marry another person, and then proclaim that person to be their one true love?

Comment: They would *probably* marry other person, they would claim this other person to be the one true love if they feel something similar, which will depend on the characteristics of this other person and their relationship. Feelings are a psychology / cognitive science subject. Does this reply your question?

Answer (score 2):

One should distinguish between the representation (declaration) of truth and truth itself. Perhaps this is as true in love as it is in philosophy.

Plato touches upon this in his dialogue (or philosophical play) the [*Symposium*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symposium_%28Plato%29). A Symposium now means an academic conference - then it meant a drinking party. They (amongst them Socrates) are in the male chambers at the house of Agathon, a playwright. Seven participants are asked to discourse and eulogise on love in turn.

Aristophanes first skips his turn as he had a bout of hiccups, when this passes he expresses a little nervousness. He says:

> I fear that in the speech which I am about to make, instead of others laughing with me, which is to the manner born of our muse and would be all the better, I shall only be laughed at by them.

Like Phaedrus, the first to make a speech he relies on myth to express his thoughts. But unlike him this is appears to be a whimsical, absurd and made up myth.

Wikipedia admits that:

> his speech has become a focus of subsequent scholarly debate, as his contribution has been seen as mere comic relief, and sometimes as satire

In brief, his myth explains the origin of love in man & woman - and in fact of man & woman too. He suggests that originally that human beings were doubled creatures with two pairs of everything - hands, feets & heads. They were enormously powerful and attempted to scale heaven so Zeus threw a thunderbolt down and sundered them in half. These became man & woman. They then ran looking for their *other half* and if they found them they proclaimed themselves *whole*.

If we take this myth seriously rather than comic relief, then Aristophanes is suggesting that true love is true and makes wholes out of halves. He doesn't suggest that these halves (men & women) will always find their other halves.

Answer (score 0):

> and then proclaim that person to be their one true love?

If we agree with your premise that their contention is correct - it is indeed 'their one true love', then they are correct in your postulated scenario as well: Since the **potential** 'one true love' never came into existence, that one that did attain existence indeed acquires the title of "their one true love".

Comment: in fact, i think this answer is both cute and correct

Answer (score 0):

I believe that love has the curious quality of being overrated by many, usually those in love, and underrated by a few more significant people, though I can only think of Marinetti (l'amore e il parlamentarismo, against love and parliamentarianism 1910).

To think about that, you might wonder about this phrase, and how it can be taken:

- this is my one true grapefruit!

A very profound lover might want to mean that only this grapefruit counts as a grapefruit, the rest are tawdry imitations of its [form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_forms#Ideal_state) and taste. Which is nonsense, even if it really is the best grapefruit in the world!

But even to insist that this very grapefruit is identical to every grapefruit both actual and possible, seems equally as dimwitted, if it's meant in any human, practical, sense.